# Send Upstream Messages from Android and iOS to application server using SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, android-location, amazon-sns

I am trying to develop a mobile application which needs to send the location and some other information to the server periodically. From the server side there are certain notifications that are been sent to the mobile and I am handling them using SNS on AWS along with GCM. Is there any way that I can send upstream messages to SNS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can call SendMessage from a mobile device just as you can from any other application.  What problem are you having?